# Can I add several values in a form to the same array without appending each value as a separate value?

Tags: php, forms

This is my code. PHP is processing the form. The ideal would be to have the first [] to act as append and the second [] to add the value into the last spot in the array.

```
<label for="file[]['title']" class="fileTitle">Description:<input type="text" name="file[]['title']"></label>
<label for="file[]['url']" class="fileUrl">Attachment URL:<input type="text" name="file[]['url']"></label>
```

So I guess my question is: Is there a short form in PHP for adding a value into the last spot of an array in the same way [] appends to an array?

**EDIT:** My question is really if there is a way to do this without numbering the array so it can be used easily in tandem with jquery $.clone();

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. Append means it's **always** the last spot in an array. From looking at your markup.. if you want the ability to have *N* number of file uploads.. each with a title and url elements, add an index to the name.. `file[0]['title'], file[0]['url'], file[1]['title']`.. etc

Comment: Please expand your question.  There's not enough context here - are you going to have MULTIPLE file title/url inputs? Are you trying to put those into a multidimensional array?

Comment: Use numbers between the brackets to disambiguate what you want.

Comment: Thanks for helping me clarify. I'd like something like file[0], file[1] without having to put in the numbers. I'm using jquery to duplicate that portion of the form and don't want to have to replace the #s.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are using [] instead of [1], [3] and so on? Because once the form is submitted you can loop over it, ignoring the numbers, no matter what they are and the key's are always consistent due to having the same index.

```
<label for="file[1]['title']" class="fileTitle">Description:<input type="text" name="file[1]['title']"></label>
<label for="file[1]['url']" class="fileUrl">Attachment URL:<input type="text" name="file[1]['url']"></label>
<label for="file[2]['title']" class="fileTitle">Description:<input type="text" name="file[2]['title']"></label>
<label for="file[2]['url']" class="fileUrl">Attachment URL:<input type="text" name="file[2]['url']"></label>

foreach($_POST['file'] as $key=>$object){
   $title=$object['title'];
   $url=$object['url'];
}
```

Comment: So no shortcuts for the jquery form hacking?